# IOS warning on background thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, background

I am downloading image on background thread and setting this image to `UIImageView` on main thread. But it is giving me some warning like

```
Using low GPU priority for background rendering
```

Also please check the below code for reference

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^(void) {
     int randomImgNum = [[contentDict valueForKey:@"imageIndex"]intValue];
     UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[Utils getImageFromIndex:randomImgNum]];
     UIImage *newBlurredImage = [image blurredImageWithRadius:5.0];
     dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
         customVieww.imgCardView.image = image;
         [self setBlurrImage:newBlurredImage];
     });
 });
```

Please let me know what could be the issue and how we can resolve it.

Also please let me know for any explanation if I miss anything.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: why DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND not  DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT

Comment: Thank you mike I have tried this solution as well but still getting the same warning

Comment: I assume the issue is caused by `blurredImageWithRadius`. Can you post the code of that particular method ?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to work on the main view you have to use the main queue 
because it can cause a problem if you use a background queue to change the UIView

Update code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     int randomImgNum = [[contentDict valueForKey:@"imageIndex"]intValue];
     UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[Utils getImageFromIndex:randomImgNum]];
     UIImage *newBlurredImage = [image blurredImageWithRadius:5.0];
     dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
         customVieww.imgCardView.image = image;
         [self setBlurrImage:newBlurredImage];
     });
 });
```

Comment: Can you please explain what is process running in background queue which is effecting UI in given question ?

Comment: Thank you bro but we are not updating any UI on background thread what will be the use of main_queue if we are not using any background thread

Answer (score 0):

check this :

According to apple documentation, iOS does not allow its GPU to any background application for obvious reason that its not on Foreground.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/ImplementingaMultitasking-awareOpenGLESApplication/ImplementingaMultitasking-awareOpenGLESApplication.html

Comment: Thank you @KKRocks but what will be the solution here where do I have gone wrong.

Comment: Create a CALayer for each rectangle and add them as sublayers of your UIImage. The CALayer hierarchy is rendered by the GPU.